# How to compile some HTML already rendered?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I' want to use a jQuery plugin with AngularJS. I initialize it with a directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            statusPopup = elem.find('div');
            scope.$on('anEvent', function(event, param) {
                popupParam = {
                    context : ".anId",
                    title : '<div class="ui label"><i ng-click="test()" class="remove icon""></i></div>' + param.title,
                    content : param.text
                };
                statusPopup.popup(popupParam).popup('show');

                scope.test = function() {
                    console.log('Clic passsed !')
                }
            })
        },
        templateUrl : 'myTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

This plugin insert on my DOM (into `myTemplate.html` view) the HTML code you can see in the `popupParam.title` parameter.

But this code contains an icon I would like to make it activated with `ng-click` directive.

How can I compile this content? I tested the following code:

```
title : $compile('<div class="ui label"><i ng-click="test()" class="remove icon""></i></div>' + param.title)(scope)
```

But it returns an object that my plugins doesn't understand. Any idea or workaround?

Comment: It returns an `angular element`/`jQuery element`. If your plugin expects a string, there is no surprize it does not understand that object. It all depends on the plugin. You could `$compile` the popup after it is inserted into the DOM (but again we need more detials on what your plugin does).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Good idea to compile the popup after it is inserted, it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For anyone having the same problem:*

`title` seems to expect some HTML as a string.
`$compile(...)(scope)` returns an angular/jQuery element.

If the plugin cannot handle that, you could:

1. pass the HTML as a string
2. let the plugin create the elements it needs
3. `$compile` the necessary elements after they are inserted into the DOM

<sub>It all depends on the plugin, of course, and what it does.</sub>